# Invalid -rpcallowip subnet specification: *.Valid are a single IP, a network/netmask or a network/CIDR

Tags: bitcoin-core, guiminer

I'm new and all this of bitcoin, but I'm trying…
I downloaded BitcoinCore and GUIminer, I made the configuration for solo minning (I created my username and password, I set Bitcoin client path) but when I tried to launch Bitcoin client as a server I got that message. What could I do?

Comment: What do you put for the `-rpcallowip` option? That's literally what the error says there's an issue with but you don't mention it at all!

Comment: I don´t know where is that option

Comment: Either you or other software (GUIminer maybe?) must have written that config option to bitcoin.conf.

Comment: I think that I fixed!, I found the -rpcallowip in "open file configuration".
But now I have "IO errors 1, tolerance 2" when I start to minning.